# Mongo scala driver: Float value can't be added

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongo-scala-driver

I am experiecing strange problem with `scala mongo driver`. When I execute the following part:

```
val doc:org.mongodb.scala.Document = org.mongodb.scala.Document(
  "junctionId"  -> junctionId,
  "efficiencyArray" -> efficiencyMap.map(p=> org.mongodb.scala.Document(
    "minute" -> p._1,
    "efficiency" -> p._2,
    "debugStuff" -> net.liftweb.json.Serialization.write(p._3)
  )),
  "totalCarCount" -> totalCarCount
)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Error:(182, 22) type mismatch;
found   : (String, Float)
required: org.mongodb.scala.bson.BsonMagnets.CanBeBsonElement
    "efficiency" -> p._2,
```

But when I do the following:

```
val doc:org.mongodb.scala.Document = org.mongodb.scala.Document(
  "junctionId"  -> junctionId,
  "efficiencyArray" -> efficiencyMap.map(p=> org.mongodb.scala.Document(
    "minute" -> p._1,
    "efficiency" -> 2.555,
    "debugStuff" -> net.liftweb.json.Serialization.write(p._3)
  )),
  "totalCarCount" -> totalCarCount
)
```

It works. However my `p._2` is `Float`.

[image]

So what is the problem here?

```
Scala version: 2.11.8
mongo-scala-driver version: 2.1.0
```

**UPDATE**:

I changed `p._2` type from `Float` to `Double` and it is worked. Still it is strange.

Comment: maybe you should use `NumberDecimal(for example 0.99)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `p._2` type from `Float` to `Double` and it is worked. Still it is strange.